# Image Scaling Android

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

I'm showing images from gallery to Imageview.

I'm using below code

```
 Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                float originalWidth = bMap.getWidth(), originalHeight = bMap.getHeight();
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
                float scale = width/originalWidth;
                float xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale)/2.0f;
                Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
                transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
                transformation.preScale(scale, scale);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bMap, transformation, paint);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(background);
```

Case 1: working.

[Original Image](http://i1027.photobucket.com/albums/y332/manishparab31/IMG_20160213_222738243%201_zpss3iosyg3.jpg)

[Output of above code.](http://i1027.photobucket.com/albums/y332/manishparab31/Screenshot_2016-02-15-12-36-58_zpsgshwcdkv.png)

Case 2: not working

[Original Image.](http://i1027.photobucket.com/albums/y332/manishparab31/IMG_20160213_222638497_zpsdbkyjivx.jpg)

[Output of above code.](http://i1027.photobucket.com/albums/y332/manishparab31/Screenshot_2016-02-15-12-37-10_zpsne95areh.png)

in case 2 why image is not getting scaled properly, to fill the imageview?
Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Why wouldn't you let ImageView scale and crop the image for you?

Comment: because I want to maintain aspect ratio..how do plan to do it?

Comment: See ImageView scaleType cropCenter.

Comment: let me try that.. :)

Comment: cropCenter worked.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Android already provides a method to create scaled bitmap. check this out [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))

Comment: but what about aspect ratio?

Comment: that is easy. Just provide the new dimensions that maintain the original aspect ratio. That is how I would do to maintain the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting it to stretch? Use fitxy.

Comment: Then you can use this since your first image was cropped on your sample too,

    <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) attribute on your ImageView in your layout xml file.

**Example:**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Then you can set your image on the `ImageView` using [`setImageUri(Uri uri)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) (I assume you have the Uri of the image to show).

Comment: The `scaleType` should be `centerInside` to meet your requirements.

Comment: Sry. It should be centerCrop. And this is definitely the right approach. If it doesn't work there is another bug in your code.